# Spring bean singelton scope with data access

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

In a spring application, by default services and dao classes are singelton. Suppose I have a update and get method.

So a thread is going to update title of a record with id=1 and while updating it another thread read the value of id=1 which going to be change in a moment. A scenario like bank money withrawal.

So my problem is, we cant synchronize such update and get operations where a single thread can only get access. So the other option would be to make scope, prototype for spring beans and then again it will create unnessacarry beans.

So how can we deal with such scenario by keeping spring defualt scope?

Comment: You're not saying anything about a database. If you had one, it would be its responsibility to deal with such scenarios. Same if you were using a `Map` (in this case you should use a `ConcurrentHashMap`)

Comment: How would `prototype` scope avoid two threads updating the record at the  same time?  I don't follow.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Suppose oracle db. So you were saying i cant do anything to hadle it from spring application but have to do it with oracle db it self by setting transaction levels right?

Comment: @ck1 you are correct. still i would face dirty reads

Comment: @Harshana you can do a lot of things, but frameworks like Hibernate already implement techniques to solve issues like this. Read about pessimistic vs optimistic locking. I suggest you go with optimistic locking, since most of the times creating a lock isn't needed.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Thanks for the information. Hibernate use versioning matching technique to prevent such scenarions know rather a locking mechanism